# Option to add public key is missing in google instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I had option to add public keys (a small plus symbol) to google instance which is missing now. now I have only existing key where I won't be able to remote it or add new. 
Given snapshot of it.
http://i59.tinypic.com/b715du.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Click on `Edit` button on the top of the page, `+ Add item` will be shown up and you can add your new keys.

[image]

[image]

Then click on `Save` button at the end of the page to save the changes.

Refer to this [public documentation link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#instance-only) for more information on adding or removing instance-level public SSH keys.

Comment: As attached in my snapshot , earlier I had that option, which is missing now.

Comment: @Dhilip Were you able to find the SSH key option at instance-level? [Here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#instance-only) is the more information on adding instance-level public SSH-keys